# Given a primitive finite set $A\subseteq\bf N$ with $0\in A$, find two more primitive sets $B,C\subseteq\bf N$ with $B\ne C$ and $A+B=A+C$

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ be the monoid of all finite subsets of $\mathbf N$ containing $0$ with the operation of set addition
$$
(X, Y) \mapsto X + Y := \{x+y: x \in X \text{ and }y \in Y\}.
$$
We call $\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ the *restricted power monoid* of $(\mathbf N, +)$, and denote by $\mathcal A(\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N))$ the set of all $X \in \mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N) \setminus \bigl\{\{0\}\bigr\}$ for which there do not exist $A, B \in \mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ with $|A|,|B| \ge 2$ and $X = A+B$. In arithmetic combinatorics, the elements of $\mathcal A(\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N))$ are usually called *primitive* (or *irreducible*) *sets*, and they are just the atoms (or irreducible elements) of the monoid $\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ in the sense of [factorization theory](https://www.crcpress.com/Non-Unique-Factorizations-Algebraic-Combinatorial-and-Analytic-Theory/Geroldinger-Halter-Koch/p/book/9781584885764). There are [deep conjectures](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/aa155-1-4) related to primitive sets in finite fields. However, my question here is much more basic:

> > **Q.** Is it true that for every $A \in \mathcal A(\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N))$ there exist $B, C \in \mathcal A(\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N))$ such that $B \ne C$, but $A+B = A+C$ (resp., $A \ne B$ and $A+C=B+C$)?

This emerged from a failed attempt I was making with a colleague to prove, by using a certain property of weak transfer homomorphisms with respect to the catenary degree, that each member in a certain class of (non-cancellative) monoids are not transfer Krull monoids in the sense of Baeth and Smertnig [J. Algebra **441** (2015), 475–551]. In the end, we have been lucky and found a different (and almost trivial) proof, but in principle I'm still interested in the above question.

Comment: The first question (namely, the one asking for the existence of atoms $B,C$ such that $B \ne C$ and $A + B = A+C$) has a positive answer, based on a density argument. I don't know about the other.

Comment: Have you considered enumerating small examples? Further, have you considered choosing $B=A$?  Even if that choice does not work for all $A$, it may be an interesting subclass.  Gerhard "It Adds To The Interest" Paseman, 2017.01.27.

Comment: Yes to your 1st question. Your 2nd question has a negative answer for small $A$: every 2-element set in $\mathcal P_{\rm fin,0}(\mathbf N)$ is an atom, and $[\![0,2]\!]$ has a unique factorization, namely $\{0,1\} + \{0,1\}$. Yet, I don't know what happens if $|A| \gg 1$. Btw, the density argument I was alluding to in my 1st comment applies to any $A\in\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)\setminus \bigl\{ \{0\}\bigr\}$, though the conclusion for an arbitrary $A$ can also be derived from the one for the case when $A$ is an atom and the fact that $\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ is atomic.

Comment: Are there any $\ A\ B\ C\ D\in \mathcal A(\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0})\ $ such that $\ \{A\ B\}\ne\{C\ D\}\ $ and $\ A+B = C+D\ $ ?

Comment: Can we have $\ C=D\ $ in the question above?

Comment: @WH. Yes, there are (I'm answering your 1st question). Consider that every $2$-element set in $\mathcal P_{{\rm fin},0}(\mathbf N)$ is an atom, and that a $3$-element set is an atom iff is not an arithmetic progression. Then, note that $\{0,1\} + \{0, 1, 3\} = \{0,1\}+\{0, 2, 3\}$. In any case, a (non-constructive) answer to your question, where at least one of the factors is arbitrarily large, follows by my 1st comment above, and I'm pretty sure that the answer to your 2nd question is negative too.